# Отклонение правки

Tags: обсуждение, отклонённые-правки

Внес правку для данного [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570601/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-yii2-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B2-acf-%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%91%D0%94).

 Внесение изменений, а именно добавление к самому вопроса текста, было взято согласно комментарию автора вопроса ( в комментах под вопросом). При редактировании причина была указана ([ссылка на редактирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/109675)). 
Но в результате правка была отклонена по причине:

> Правка не соответствует исходному содержанию сообщения. Даже правки,
>   которые призваны изменить сообщение в корне, должны быть выполнены с
>   соблюдением идей автора сообщения.

Просьба пояснить причину отказа в редактировании, поскольку идея автора сообщения была сохранена, более, дополнена согласно его комментарию к вопросу.

Comment: Люди-роботы в очереди проверок - нередкое явление.

Comment: Описанной причине отклонения правка точно не соответствует. Да и вообще я не вижу причин её отклонять.

Comment: Повторите правку, мы примем )

Comment: Можете в чат написать с просьбой проверить, там довольно адекватные люди сидят )) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: @Nofate пардон, моя ошибка!

Comment: Согласен с Вами, что правка имеет смысл. Извините, не внимательно прочел Ваш комментарий. Впредь буду внимательнее читать комментарии к правкам.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же, данную правку отклонять не следовало, т.к. в описании явно указано:

> Добавление согласно комментарию автора вопроса

Но если этот комментарий не заметить, или не сходить в сам вопрос и почитать комментарии под ним, на первый взгляд может показаться, что в правке предложена какая-то отсебятина, никак не связанная с исходным сообщением ТС или его задумкой.

Может быть в подобных проверках надо как-то лучше выделять причину правки, а может быть ревьюверы просто должны быть более внимательны и не шлёпать "отклонить" без чуть более усердного разбора в попытке отстрелять побыстрее дневную порцию проверок.

Кстати, сейчас производится [редизайн страниц очередей проверок](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/339911), но не очень понятно, когда это может дойти до ruSO и станет ли от этого меньше процент отклонения правок, которые реально не стоило отклонять.